# Limiting the decimal point into 4 digits in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, number-formatting

I can limit the decimal point when I declare the variable as decimal though I can't when I declare it as a string. Because I need it in string datatype.

```vb
Dim result As Decimal
result = ComputationResult
Textbox1.Text = result.ToString("N4")
```

^^ The above code works

But this doesn't :

```vb
Dim result As String
result = ComputationResult
Textbox1.Text = result.ToString("N4")
```

Comment: If you set [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project (and set it as the default for new projects) then Visual Studio can point out where that sort of thing goes wrong, giving you an opportunity to decide what variable types are correct for which variables.

Comment: Where does `ComputationResult` come from?

Comment: You can't format a `String`. You can only format something as a `String`. What you are doing in the first code snippet is what you should be doing, i.e. storing numbers in numeric data types and then formatting as an appropriate `String` at the point you actually need a `String`, e.g. for display. String numbers as text is wrong from the outset, so the fact that it doesn't work the way you want it to should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `cumputationResult` is already a string, convert it to a decimal using `Decimal.Parse`, then do the number formatting on it.

```vb
Dim cumputationResult = "1.234567"
Textbox1.Text = Decimal.Parse(cumputationResult).ToString("N4")
```

Answer (score 1):

If `ComputationResult` is a `Decimal`, when `result` is declared as a string you have an implicit conversion from `Decimal` to `String` on this line using the default format:

```
 result = ComputationResult
```

So now `result` is already a string, and you lost the opportunity to use numeric format strings. The "N4" in the `ToString()` call has no meaning:

```
 Textbox1.Text = result.ToString("N4")
```

It's trying to use [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tostring?view=net-7.0#system-string-tostring(system-iformatprovider)), where `N4` will fail to match any format provider... but it doesn't matter, because the linked documentation says this argument is **ignored** anyway:

> provider is reserved, and does not currently participate in this operation.
>
> Because this method simply returns the current string unchanged, there is no need to call it directly.

On the other hand, if `ComputationResult` is a `String`, the version where `result` is a `Decimal` forces an implicit conversion from `String` to `Decimal`, which allows allows the `result.ToString("N4")` call to use [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tostring?view=net-7.0#system-decimal-tostring(system-string)) that knows about format strings.

---

What we learn from this is **data types matter!** Better developers are aware of the data type in play at every level of their expressions, and know how to use the appropriate types in the appropriate places, while avoiding needless conversions.

Remember, thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, converting between a number (or date) and a string is **FAR** slower and more error-prone than you expect. It's not the quick or simple operation we'd like it to be, but rather something to avoid. The best plan is generally to keep a value in a number type for as long as possible, and **only** convert to string for output at the last possible moment.

Really, the fact the `result = ComputationResult` assignment compiles for both samples tells me you have both `Option Strict` and `Option Infer` turned off, and that's **REALLY BAD!** You should turn at least one of those on, and then go correct the resulting errors in your program until the code compiles again. You will be *SO MUCH BETTER OFF* for this work: your code will be faster, MUCH less likely to crash, and it will actually make you a faster developer once you learn to adapt to the constraint.

---

Since we don't know that actual type of `ComputationResult`, there are two possible correct versions of the code. Either you want this if it's a String:

```
Textbox1.Text = Decimal.Parse(ComputationResult).ToString("N4")
```

or this if it's a Decimal:

```
Textbox1.Text = ComputationResult.ToString("N4")
```

And really, if `ComputationResult` is defined in a sane way it will already be a `Decimal`.

Finally, it looks like `ComputationResult` *might* be a method with no arguments. While VB.Net still supports calling methods without parentheses for the argument list, *you should not do that*. For .Net, ALWAYS use parentheses when calling your methods.

```
Textbox1.Text = ComputationResult().ToString("N4")
```

But if it's not the case `ComputationResult` is a method you can ignore this last item.

Comment: Do you mean that `Option Strict` should be off and only `Option Strict` should be turned on?

Comment: @MichaelFoster I mean it looks like both Option Strict and Option Infer are turned off. I strongly believe at least one of those should be turned on.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Option Strict` should be on and `Option Infer` should be off. I don't seem to be able to edit, only delete that comment. If `Option Strict` is off, then shortening conversions are allowed.

Comment: Maybe. I don't use VB nearly as often in recent years, so I'm less clear today on how the two interact and my mental model may be failing. I just know its nuts to work in .Net without some reasonable enforced type checking.